# Posix semaphore for synchronisation between two different processes

Tags: linux, posix, embedded-linux, semaphore

I have two processes say A and B. I need to achieve synchronization between these two using semaphore. Is it possible to use POSIX semaphore for two different process.If not what other options are there to achieve same.
Note: A and B are two separate executable binaries.
I am using Linux 4.X.

Comment: Get started by reading the "sem_overview" man page.

Comment: What kind of synchronization?

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès when process A will post semaphore then and process B should start its execution otherwise wait for semaphore.

Comment: Very standard task, search on the net